# ClearCase Remote Client query

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, clearcase-remote-client

The old version of ClearCase Remote Client 7.1, the menu "Add resources to source control" was always active , it would scan through the library and add  any uncatalogued elements  to ClearCase.  However when ClearCase Remote Client is upgraded to 8.0 it is only  active when select a file that is yet to be added. It no longer searches the library but requires the user to manually locate files that need to be added. Is this a expected behaviour between CCRC 7.1 & 8.0?

Comment: That looks like the behavior described in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSJMXE_8.5.1/com.ibm.rational.test.ft.doc/topics/t_ccrc_int_add_project.html indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CC Version 7 is out of scope for more than 3 years now. I have 8.0.1.3 and I don't see the "Add resource .." you are talking about but just "add to source control" which is active only when clicking on an private element that hasn't been added to CC at all.

I think you can change the menu from ClearCase homebase -> Options -> Context Menu Editor.

To see the changes from CC 7 to CC 8, try to search IBM CC page, like

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21972269

Or

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21322828

Or alike.

Enjoy,
Elyahu

P.S. The best solution would be moving to GIT :-)